# How can I use regex to match “the end” without allowing a newline there?

Tags: python, regex, newline

`^abc$` matches the string `abc`, but also `abc\n` (with a trailing newline).

How can I let it match only strings without newline?

(Having Python in mind, but should be a general regex problem.)

Comment: Depending on your need, `'abc\n'.strip()` may be a useful alternative to using `\Z`.

Comment: When you say *should be a general regex problem* do you mean in multiple flavors of regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `$` use `\Z` which matches only at the end of the string.

```
>>> re.match(r'^abc\Z', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02469560>
>>> re.match(r'^abc\Z', 'abc\n')
>>>
```

**Note:** This answer depends specifically on the meaning of `\Z` in Python.  This concept is [often spelled](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#Z) `\z` in other regex implementations.  You could also use a negative-lookahead assertion, but the syntax for that also varies across regex implementations.  See [dawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32977117/1322401) for an example using negative-lookahead assertions in Python.

Comment: If the OP intended on finding the beginning and end of a string, it should be '\Aabc\Z'.  Otherwise it will only match if it's at the only thing on the line.

Comment: There is wide variability of `\Z` and `\z` in different regex engines. See [HERE.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#Z) This works in Python by not always in or flavors of regex. Specifically, in Java, PCRE, .NET, `\Z` matches before the final (but not including) `\n` so this is the opposite of what is wanted on these other languages. In other languages, you would use a `\z` A negative lookahead is a more platform agnostic.

Comment: @ergonaut: `match()` starts at the *beginning* of the string, `^` nor `\A` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Pyson:  Fair enough, but the question was regarding Python's regular expressions.

Comment: @ergonaut:  The OP used the word "match".  However, it is possible he meant Python's `re.search` instead of `re.match`.  I left `^` in the regex to preserve the ambiguity present in the question and addressed the main part of the question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Quoting: (Having Python in mind, *but should be a general regex problem.*)

Comment: @Pyson:  I took that to mean "I want a Python solution, but it's something that anyone who knows regex can answer."  Whereas you took that to mean "I want a regex that works across languages."

Comment: Thanks. The issue is bigger though: `\Z` is unique to Python and some would say completely and utterly broken. Most see `\Z` as 'end of string, ignoring line terminator' as it is in Perl. It is the opposite in Python. I removed my dv tho.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead to make sure there is no `\n`:

```
>>> re.search(r'^abc(?!\n)$', s1)
>>> re.search(r'^abc(?!\n)$', s2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a716a58>
>>> re.search(r'^abc(?!\n)$', 'abcdefg')
>>>
```

Which works the same in most other modern regex flavors.

Perl:

```
  DB<11> print 'match' if "abc\n" =~ /^abc(?!\n)$/

  DB<12> print 'match' if "abc" =~ /^abc(?!\n)$/              
match
```

Ruby:

```
irb(main):031:0> "abc"[/^abc(?!\n)$/]
=> "abc"
irb(main):032:0> "abc\n"[/^abc(?!\n)$/]
=> nil
```

PHP:

```
$ php -r 'print preg_match("/^abc(?!\n)$/", "abc\n");'
0
$ php -r 'print preg_match("/^abc(?!\n)$/", "abc");'
1
```

Comment: I think `/^abc(?![\s\S])/` is better and more idiomatic regex. Works in older regex flavors as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is a negative lookahead, so it will not find matches if it's at the end of the line, but anywhere else.

```
>>> re.search('abc(?!\n)','abc\n')
>>> re.search('abc(?!\n)','abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103eceac0>
```

Comment: This also matches `'abcwtf'` and `'wtfabc'`.  From my reading of the question neither of these are wanted.

Comment: where in the OP is that wrong?, need clarification.

Comment: The OP used `$` to try to match to the end of the string.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this applies to the regex engine in python, but you can check out.[negative\positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
You can use negative look ahead to see if \n is after "abc".